# access to reception sensor information with iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

Is there a way to programmatically access the reception level sensor with iPhone SDK 3.1?

Thanks,

Nava

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer is - currently impossible, please fill feature report...